# Winform C# : Node selection on expansion and collapse gets change at the bottom of the Treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am using a Treeview in my windows form but getting some issue. My Node selection on expansion and collapse gets change at the bottom of the Treeview. I am using afterselect and MosueDown event. My problem is I have to deal with AfterSelect and MouseDown event both in my app as I am using Right click context menu as well. Below is the sample code that I am trying to use. Is there a way or advice to resolve this issue?

```
 private void trView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
       if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
       {
          trView.SelectedNode = trView.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);
       }
      //trView.SelectedNode.EnsureVisible(); //tried this as well

      trView.SelectedNode.Toggle(); // on this toggle selection changes butonly at the bottom (more specifically for last 3 nodes)
 }

 private void trView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
 {
    // Code to add child nodes to a selection.
 }
```

[image]

In the above pic when I am selecting Project Beyond Node, UAT Data gets selected. This is only happening in last 3 nodes. I am stuck. Please help.

Comment: That Toggle() call is a pretty bad randomizer, it makes left-clicks behave very badly.  At MouseDown the node isn't selected yet so it expands the completely wrong node.  Remove it and let the AfterSelect event handler call Expand().

Comment: Since you are checking `if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)` so you wont have any issue with `+/-`. If you didn't have that criteria you should use `TreeView.HitTest` and check if the mouse down is on `+/-` then don't toggle and let the standard behavior be done.

Comment: Expand in Afterslect causes another problem and to avoid I started using .Toggle() in mousedown. Toggle works for all the nodes except for last 3 nodes.

Comment: In general performing toggle should be done after click on `+/-` because selection is a different operation than clicking on `+/-`. But you can simply mix `var node = treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y)` and `var hti = treeView1.HitTest(e.Location);` and `e.Button` to satisfy any requirement on mouse down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of these options:

1. Use `MouseDown` event, and after setting `SelectedNode`, `Toggle` it using `BeginInvoke`:

   ```
   private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
       {
           treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);
           treeView1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { treeView1.SelectedNode.Toggle(); }));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use `NodeMouseClick` event:

   ```
   private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
       {
           treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);
           treeView1.SelectedNode.Toggle();
       }
   }
   ```

**Note**

In general performing toggle should be done after click on `+/-` because selection is a different operation than clicking on `+/-`. But you can simply mix some criteria based on `var node = treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y)` and `var hti = treeView1.HitTest(e.Location);` and `e.Button` to satisfy any requirement on mouse down.

For example in below code, the left click and right click works in the same way, both of them select the node and both toggle the selected node.

```
private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var node = treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);
    var hti = treeView1.HitTest(e.Location);
    if (node == null)
        return;
    treeView1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => treeView1.SelectedNode = node));
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        node.Toggle();
    }
    else if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        if (hti.Location != TreeViewHitTestLocations.PlusMinus)
            node.Toggle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reza for the reply. I tried both the solutions. First one works with one issue. It actually selects the the first child node and then the original clicked node gets selected. Problem is with my last child node. whenever my last node is selected, a list of some files will appear in my listview on the right side of my treeview. So when I click one node above the last child node. Listview appears. For the second solution, clicking on the +  icon does not  expands my node. any advice to solve this?

Comment: When using the criteria `if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)` you wont have `+/-` issue. Also you can check if the mouse down is not over a `+/-` by checking the result of [`HitTest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.hittest(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `TreeView`.

Comment: while using if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) I am only able to expand or collapse a node by clicking + - Icon and not directly clicking the node text. solution works if I only go with one way to expand or collapse. Either use of +- or direct click on node but not both.

Comment: It depends on your requirements. Read the answer of your previous question. I can't see any requirement in this question about the way of expanding or collapsing. But you can simply satisfy any criteria which you need.

Comment: Ok..I will try to make few more change along with your solution. Will post here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Exactly..I already made use of HitTest and satisfied my requirement. Thank you so much for the help.